# Support for multiple types of comment syntax in code blocks

Tags: feature-request, comments, syntax-highlighting, code

You can comment a statement in T-SQL (for SQL Server) using --

StackOverflow does not show this as a comment.

```
--Comment goes here and code follows
INSERT INTO TABLE ....
```

The C# style comment shows up properly.

```
/*Comment goes here and code follows*/
//Comment goes here and code follows
INSERT INTO TABLE ....
```

I think the SQL Server style should be supported as well.

Comment: Take it up with Google, man: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/ This functionality is developed out-of-house.

Comment: VB comments (start with `'`) don't work either. I usually do this: `''//` to trick the highlighter

Comment: How does one accept a comment as an answer?!?!?!