# CMD `::` autoformats badly

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

From [How to run a PowerShell script within a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609985/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-within-a-dos-batch-file/2611487#2611487)

There's an idiom in CMD scripts to use `::` as a comment delimiter. (`:` means a label, so `::` gets ignored.)  I use it because I think it's easier to read than `REM`.

I wrote this in an answer:

```
@@:: This prolog allows a PowerShell script to be embedded in a .CMD file.
@@:: Any non-PowerShell content must be preceeded by "@@"
@@setlocal
@@set POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%*
@@if defined POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS set POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS:"=\"%
@@PowerShell -Command Invoke-Expression $('$args=@(^&{$args} %POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS%);'+[String]::Join(';',$((Get-Content '%~f0') -notmatch '^^@@'))) & goto :EOF
```

which formatted like this (as of 9 April 2010; red circle added):
[image]
<sub>(source: [ggpht.com](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_Ea_bL5v3E3s/S7_Za-NR1eI/AAAAAAAAAK4/AWf-GPA-hzQ/s800/CMD%20comment.jpg))</sub>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/syntax-highlighting-hints http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24719/syntax-highlighting-broken http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14549/syntax-highlighting-is-inconsistent http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30077/support-for-multiple-types-of-comment-syntax-in-code-blocks

Comment: -1 for not using a freehand circle

Comment: That's 5 issues with code formatting so far; there are surely more.  I hope the SO team steps back and looks at the big picture, especially since SO is about *programming* so making code look good is important!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue with Google Prettify and cannot be addressed by the SE Development team.

Answer (score 5):

the SO syntax highlighter is not a magical language detector. It uses simple rules for colorization that happens to work decently with most languages. PowerShell is apparently not one of them.

Comment: Yeah, I get that SO's syntax highlighter is general-purpose that way. Note that the issue here is with CMD, not with PowerShell.  (When I read what you wrote, I think you are telling me I shouldn't have reported this issue. Do you think the SO team doesn't want to know about it?)

Comment: @Jay, I think this will be closed as a will-not-fix or by-design bug. The SO team has better things to do than change it so it works with CMD or Powershell or any other language perfectly. Plus, any changes to the highlighting engine at this point would cause old posts to highlight differently, possibly for the worse. If you want perfect syntax highlighting, put it on pastebin.com or similar.

Comment: will-not-fix is fine; the StackOverflow team gets to decide where to put their energy. by-design seems nuts: who would say that this behavior is desirable? As for back-compat, it would be possible to teach the formatter to apply old rules to posts before a certain date, and new rules to newer posts. Again, up to the SO team to decide what they want to do.

Comment: @Jay that just adds a lot of complicated implementation details for very little real benefit. If you want that, go cast your vote for that feature-request for a language selector for code formatting

Answer (score 3):

You can do something similar to what the [VB crowd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/vb-net-syntax-highligting-does-not-properly-support-comment) does:

```
@@::// This prolog allows a PowerShell script to be embedded in a .CMD file.
@@::// Any non-PowerShell content must be preceeded by "@@"
@@setlocal
@@set POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%*
@@if defined POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS set POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS=%POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS:"=\"%
@@PowerShell -Command Invoke-Expression $('$args=@(^&{$args} %POWERSHELL_BAT_ARGS%);'+[String]::Join(';',$((Get-Content '%~f0') -notmatch '^^@@'))) & goto :EOF
```

`@@::#` will also work.

Not a great solution, but you can render the code properly.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip to know. This is an excellent example of "Each design pattern is a sign of a weakness in the programming language to which it applies".